# Google Analytics medium : "banner" and "Banner" (not in the same channel group)

Tags: google-analytics, channel, banner

I'm exploring Google Analytics features and I've noticed something surprising.

Unless I'm mistaken, the `banner` medium is associated with the default system channel group `Display`, although the `Banner` medium is associated with the ground `(Other)`.

According to the [Default channel definitions](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/3297892?hl=en), the Display group use the regex `^(display|cpm|banner)$`

The filters on regex seems to be case-insensitive(as explained [here](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/v3/reference#filterExpressions%5d)). As a result, when I try to get the data for the Google Analytics API when the filter `ga:medium=~^(display|cpm|banner)$,ga:adDistributionNetwork==Content;ga:adFormat!=Text`, I get results for both "banner" and "Banner" medium.

However, when I check on the Google Analytics website, the `banner` medium is in the `Display` group, and the `Banner` is in the `(Other)` group.

Could you please confirm me this point (and explain if possible :)) ?

Thanks a lot !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Banner` is being placed under `(Other)` because it is capitalized. What you can do is create a filter that will convert any campaign parameters to lowerCase.

To do this:

1. Create a new filter > select "Custom Filter"
2. Select the Lowercase filter
3. And from the dropdown, select Campaign Medium

This will convert all of your campaign mediums to lowercase, and will place them in the correct channel grouping.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your answer! If I set up these filters, will they affect only new data, or will they update the data already stored?

Comment: Filters are not retroactive. So it will only affect new data.